# Multimedia Component : Not able to upload Image in multimedia component

Tags: multimedia, image

I'm doing creating a multimedia component using the multimedia schema that allows PNG, JPEG, GIF,etc. But while creating a component I'm not able to upload images. It doesn't show anything.  (Using Tridion 2013 SP1)

Comment: Are you creating a multimedia component? Are you using the Resource Type as "Uploaded"? Can you attach a screen shot on what you are seeing now? Refer official documentation as well! http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B452AB7F-06EB-4F8D-B313-20BABC4B0BA6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the hotfixes released by SDL for Chrome issues with Multimedia uploads?

The hotfixes can be found here for 2013 SP1 https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1/index.aspx

and here for 2013 SP1 Hr1
https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1_HR1/index.aspx

Comment: hotfixes links are not working.

Comment: You would have to login to sdltridionworld first before trying to download.